# How to make text completely unselectable and uncopy-able?

Tags: html, css, text, copying

You guys know this code, right ?

```
div {
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
    -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */

    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;          
}
```

Well, while you would use **ctrl + a** (or **cmd + a** on a *mac*) on a page and nothing visible seems selected, you can still copy it using **ctrl + v** (or **cmd + v** on a *mac*) and paste it in a *Word*-document (for example) or copy the text from the source code, so basically if you decide to use it, do know it's useless.

But I do have seen some websites which somehow manage to make text unselectable and uncopy-able. How would these guys do it ?

Comment: Will you be happy with a JavaScript solution?

Comment: I don't care what script language it is, as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: I'm wondering... Why you wanna do this? just asking.

Comment: First of all out of convenience: some stuff like link text in a menu or a sidebar isn't of any value to copy. Second of all, to ensure my pictures are being protected even more just in case a watermark doesn't help (people who use my pictures in personal works and have few IT-knowledge). That's why.

Comment: They can always see the source code. even if you do it with JavaScript. they can still bypass it by disabling JavaScript.

I suggest you use watermark on your photos. It's better in my opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Copying on a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365272/disable-copying-on-a-website)