# How to prevent user from copy and pasting the text in the CK editor 5 with angular

Tags: angular, copy-paste, ckeditor5

I want to block copy paste action in the CK Editor.
I tried using the custom directive to block the cut copy paste action. But not able to use that directive in the CK Editor.

---

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBlockCopyPaste]'
})

export class BlockCopyPasteDirective {

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('paste',['$event']) blockPaste(e: KeyboardEvent){
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  @HostListener('copy',['$event'] blockCopy(e: KeyboardEvent){
      e.preventDefault();
  }
 
  @HostListener('cut',['$event']) blockCut(e: KeyboardEvent){
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

---

````
    [formControl]="ckeditorFormControl" [config]="config" appBlockCopyPaste ></ckeditor>```


----------


adding appBlockCopyPaste is also not restricting me from copy paste.
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Copying on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365272/disable-copying-on-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable copy, but paste is absolutely possible!

[documentation for CKEditor events](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_angular.html#supported-output-properties)

ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  content = '';
  config = {
    removeButtons: 'copy',
  };

  cancel(x) {
    x.cancel();
  }
}
```

html

```
<p>CK - Editor Example</p>

<!-- <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor> -->
<ckeditor
  [data]="content"
  [config]="config"
  (paste)="cancel($event)"
  (copy)="cancel($event)"
></ckeditor>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ck-editor-42pi47)